# How could Misaka 10032 be measuring Touma's life signals while holding his right hand

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

Index episode 14 around 14:00 minutes.

Touma awakens to find his right hand on Misaka 10032's chest. 10032 then states that she placed his hand there herself, and that she was reading electrical currents to measure his life signs.

Given that Imagine Breaker is a passive power, how could that be possible?

So, is it

1. A white lie. She wasn't reading him. Not likely because Misaka clones usually don't lie and show little emotion.
2. A plot hole. They just forgot what power was in the hand.
3. An animation faux. She was actually holding his left hand in the Light Novel.

Comment: maybe she's not using a method that Imagine Breaker would cancel out, something that's just generic technology since it's not like appliances and that shut down if Touma uses his right hand right?

Comment: @Memor-X whille it is true Imagine Breaker only works on the supernatural, there is no device in her hands, and she mentions measuring brainwaves....

Comment: It has been shown that Touma was always awake when he uses Imagine Breaker. Maybe it just won't activate if he is unconscious?

Comment: @AyaseEri during the arc in Italy, the Amakusa church uses Toumas hand to destroy magical clothes while he was unconscious

Comment: Interesting question. I verified that it was his right arm in the manga, but I'd like to see what the light novels say. Could it be because her power is reading electrical current internally (inside his arm), and not coming in contact with Imagine Breaker? There were also some cases where Imagine Breaker wasn't very effective because the power regenerated too quickly (A certain Level 6 esper comes to mind). So it could be that since Touma is in direct contact with Misaka 10032's body, Imagine Breaker can't negate her abilities quickly enough to stop her from using them.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude there is no level 6 esper. At least not permanently. There are angel-class esper (prollly the same guy you are referring to), but they are in another level of power. And when he held Mikoto, her electromaster powers were disabled, so that might not be the case.

Comment: I was referring to Level 6 Misaka in volume 10 of the Railgun manga. Touma's arm had to turn into a dragon to stop her (or whatever the heck happened).

Comment: Hm... I was going to suggest that since Misaka 10032 was holding his wrist and Imagine Breaker is in his hand, she wouldn't be affected, but Kuroko was holding Touma's arm at a point just under his elbow and was unable to teleport (using the Index manga as a reference).

Comment: @ShayminGratitude that was very temporary. And Mikoto was going to die (and wipe out Tokyo entirely) if Touma hadn't stopped her. Theoretically, the only 5 that could get to 6 permanently is Accelerator. But that project stopped at 50.155% completion anyway.

Comment: With only a vague idea of the context, my guess is that it could be [pulse oximetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_oximetry)

Comment: If she was lying, that wouldn't be the first time she lied to him as a joke: in the anime's 2nd season, ep11 at 10:58, she lies about analyzing fingerprints on a vending machine and matching them to his.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer, but as the question does specifically ask about whether there is a difference between the light novels and the other versions, here are my findings:

In Yen Press's English translation of *A Certain Magical Index: Volume 3*, which hand of Touma's that Misaka 10032 is holding to her chest is unspecified. Here's the quote:

> Lastly, he noticed Little Misaka's hands embracing one of his. 
> It didn't really *matter*, but she was holding both of her hands to her chest...

Furthermore, it also isn't specified which side of the bed Misaka 10032 is sitting on:

> After all, the only person in the room was Little Misaka, quietly sitting on a chair at the side of the bed-

Misaka 10032's explanation for why she was holding Touma's hand to her chest are same in the manga and light novel: she says she's measuring his brain waves and pulse via bioelectricity. Neither offers any more insight than that.

From this, one might find it reasonable to conclude that it was indeed an error introduced by the anime and that by the ambiguity in the light novels, we should conclude it was Touma's left hand because it would be impossible for Misaka 10032 to read his bioelectricity from his right.

Comment: Have my gratitude, my vote and the green checkmark.